# How to open a Blank App (XAML) in Visual Studio 2015 and later? - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to study from C# Head First and it seems like the blank app (XAML) option only exists in visual studio express 2012 (I tried today's express as well as community with no luck finding that option), I tried few of the options that seemed to be similar but none provides the files requested by the guide.

*sorry for the bad English/grammer, English is not my native language.

Comment: it probably has a different name than `blank app`, try `WPF Application`

Comment: Tried both, they don't cut it.

Comment: Love the fact that everyone has missed the point that an XAML app is actually a windows store app. Yes, WPF uses xaml files, but it isn't an XAML app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book uses the 2013 version, which has support for XAML with the blank app feature. On later versions, the closest you come is WPF, which is pretty close even providing you with XAML. But dont worry, the book realizes that and links to here(http://cdn.oreilly.com/oreilly/pdfs/hfcsharp3e_WPF_download.pdf). The WPF versions of the tasks in the book. Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

*Blank* is a bit of a misnomer and should not be taken literally. Blank in their case means no controls on a newly created WPF app. Simply choose `WPF Application`:

[image]

---

Then bring up the `Solution Explorer` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to see the project files created:

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't provide the files the guide need

Comment: It wants MainPage.xaml, MainPage.Xaml.cs and App.xaml.csMainPage

Comment: @Tomer8009 see update, but once the project is created it should have the files necessary.

Comment: the problem seems to be that I don't have the damn windows store option

Comment: @Tomer8009 try the latest Visual studio Community edition (free) [Free Dev Tools - Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)

Comment: I know that, but (sorry for the dumb question) are those identical to MainPage.xaml, MainPage.Xaml.cs and App.xaml.csMainPage?

Comment: And the lastest version is what I have, I downloaded it from the official site 3 hours ago

Comment: @Tomer8009 Is "App.xaml.csMainPage" a typo? There is a "App.xaml.cs" file as well as the MainPage which comprises of two files "MainPage.Xaml" and its code behind "MainPage.cs".

Comment: @Tomer8009 Use the default *window* to do your work. For page and windows are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

http://cdn.oreilly.com/oreilly/pdfs/hfcsharp3e_WPF_download.pdf

In the first chapter, the book mentioned that WPF is an alternative to Blank XAML! :)

Answer (score 1):

'Blank project' is the American way of saying an empty project. I am using Visual Studio 2019 -->Create a new project-->WPF App (.NET Core)
[screenshot of the WPF App option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2fuF.png)